# How to pass multiple -D arguments to driver-java-options in spark submit command

Tags: java, command-line, apache-spark-2.0

I am running a spark-submit command using java method i.e.  `Runtime.getRunTime().exec("<SPARK_SUBMIT_COMMAND>").`

The spark-submit command is like:

```
spark-submit \
--driver.java.options "-Dapp.name=abc -Dapp.id=123" \
--class com.abc.test.AppLauncher \
Spark-App.jar \
<Other required application parameters>
```

The above command works perfectly fine if I directly execute from the unix terminal, from that directory location where the jar is present BUT

when I run the same command from Runtime.getRunTime().exec("");
It gives below error:

Unrecognized option: -Dapp.id=123

Could someone please help me on this issue?

I tried below options but they did not work:
 --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dapp.name=abc -Dapp.id=123"
   --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dapp.name=abc -Dapp.id=123"

Comment: try using single quotes --driver.java.options= '-Dapp.name=abc -Dapp.id=123'